# debugging an unmanaged Neo4j extension

Tags: java, debugging, neo4j, server

I just started developing an unmanaged extension for Neo4j server using the Graphaware framework. Everything is fine so far. Even unit tests are working. But I would like to actually debug the extension running the Neo4j server from within Intellij.

Can anybody give me a hint on how to do that?

Many thanks in advance,
Oliver

PS: This extension is being called via rest interface from a separate web server providing hosting the actual web application.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable jvm remote debugging in `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`. Amend a new line to this file:

```
wrapper.java.additional=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Xdebug-Xnoagent-Djava.compiler=NONE-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

In case you want to debug the startup sequence as well, use set suspend=y above.

In your debugger setup a remote debugging session to `localhost:5005` or `myhostname:5005`.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply.

Actually, I intended to start up the server from within the IDE (Jetrains Intellij) using a Run/Debug configuration. And I hoped to be able to just set "Main class", "VM options", "Environment variables" etc. like it is possible with quite a few other server implementations.

Do you know what settings would be necessary to accomplish that or if that is possible at all?

Comment: You just have to start the Bootstrapper, check the `bin/neo4j` script for the concrete main class and java system properties.

Comment: This does not seem to work with Neo4j 3.0.5. Is there any update?

Answer (score 3):

For neo4j 3.0 you have to amend this line to `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`.

```
dbms.jvm.additional=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```