# How to set breakpoints and debug an unmanaged extension

Tags: netbeans, neo4j

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692597/debugging-an-unmanaged-neo4j-extension) and I'm able to start neo4j and start a remote debugging session in my Netbeans.

My question is how do I place a breakpoint so I can see what my unmanaged extension is doing step by step. I'm running Neo4j 3.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the section on Setting Breakpoints on page 9 of the chapter on [Debugging](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/nbfieldguide/Chapter5-Debugging.pdf) in the NetBean User Guide.

Comment: the problem is not with netbeans. Is with the way unmanaged extensions in neo4j work